# What is it designed for, the bundle generated by Cocoapods pod lib create

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

There is a bundle included in the project created by pod lib create:

[image: There is an empty bundle created by pod lib create]

I'm curious what is its purpose and cannot find any document mentioning it yet. Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be to do with assigning a framework per target, we removed this in 0.38, so you should end up seeing something more like this: [image]

Where the `Pods-Aerodramus_Example` and `Pods-Aerodramus_Tests` only represent a collection of Pods within that target.

[image]